# How to make the view update when the view model changes in MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, windows-store-apps

I am trying to implement MVVM, but my view is not updating when the view model changes. This is my view model:

```
public class ViewModelDealDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Deal selectedDeal;

    public Deal SelectedDeal
    {
        get { return selectedDeal; }
        set
        {
            selectedDeal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In my XAML for the view I have this:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
       <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDeal.Title, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The deal class:

```
public class Deal
{
    private string title;
    private float price;

    public Deal()
    {
        this.title = "Example";    
    }

    public Deal(string title, float price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public float Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }
}
```

When the application starts the value is correct, but when SelectedDeal changes, the view doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The path of your binding is nested.To make it work, your **Deal** class should implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** too. Otherwise, it will not be triggered unless **SelectedDeal** is changed. I would suggest you make your view models all inherited from **BindableBase**. It would make your life much easier.

```
   public class ViewModelDealDetails: BindableBase
    {
        private Deal selectedDeal;

        public Deal SelectedDeal
        {
            get { return selectedDeal; }
            set { SetProperty(ref selectedDeal, value); }
        }

    }

    public class Deal: BindableBase
    {
        private string title;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
        }
    }
```

The above code should work.

BTW:
If you have no access to the code of Deal class, then to trigger the binding you will have to recreate an instance of **SelectedDeal** each time when the value of **Title** is changed.